# Pycairo: How to correctly instance cairo.XlibSurface()?

Tags: python, cairo, xlib, pycairo

I'm trying to create widgets with Pycairo to monitor systems, like Conky.
I'm trying to draw directly on X, using Cairo Surface with Xlib.

When I try to instantiate the cairo.XlibSurface() class, an error is returned:

```
TypeError: The XlibSurface type cannot be directly instantiated
```

My simple code:

```
import cairo
surface = cairo.XlibSurface()
```

How to correctly instance cairo.XlibSurface() ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no easy way - maybe you'd better be using Cairo through GTK - for which an up-to-date example can be seem here: https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/cairo_integration.html

Comment: With gtk is ease, but i want integrate with xlib and draw in X not gtk window.
I can't find any example of pycairo with xlib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Not solved the question: How to use Pycairo with Xlib, but an elegant alternative using Gtk and Pycairo.*

*The mystery of how to use Pycairo with Xlib continues.*

Using Gtk window with `Gdk.WindowTypeHint.DESKTOP`, getting elegant output.

```py
import gi
gi.require_versions({
    'Gdk':  '3.0',
    'Gtk':  '3.0',
    'Wnck': '3.0',
    'Gst':  '1.0',
    'AppIndicator3': '0.1',
})

from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk
import cairo


class Example(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.tran_setup()
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.connect("draw", self.on_draw)
        # self.set_title("Transparent window")
        self.resize(300, 250)
        self.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.NONE)
        self.move(0, 40)
        self.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
        
        # The magic is here
        self.set_type_hint(Gdk.WindowTypeHint.DESKTOP)

        self.show_all()

    def tran_setup(self):
        self.set_app_paintable(True)
        screen = self.get_screen()

        #print(self.get_type_hint())

        visual = screen.get_rgba_visual()
        if visual != None and screen.is_composited():
            self.set_visual(visual)

    def on_draw(self, wid, cr):
        cr.set_source_rgba(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4)
        cr.set_operator(cairo.OPERATOR_SOURCE)
        cr.paint()

        cr.set_source_rgb(0.6, 0.6, 0.6)

        cr.rectangle(20, 20, 120, 80)
        cr.fill()

        self.draw(cr)

    def draw(self, cr):
        cr.set_source_rgb(0, 256, 256)
        cr.rectangle(180, 20, 80, 80)
        cr.fill()


def main():
    app = Example()
    Gtk.main()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

[image: Print]

Answer (score 1):

[not a complete answer]
I have enough snippets that this might be more useful as an answer than as a comment. Sorry for not getting to the bottom of this.

The [documentation for PyCairo XlibSurface](https://pycairo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/surfaces.html#cairo.XlibSurface) itself only mentions it can be instantiated by certain calls to GTK - and I am not sure if that is the old bindings to GTK2 only . I could find a snippet to get me a Cairo context using GTK +3, but it seems it is not feasible, without resorting to ctypes, to go back from the Cairo context to the Surface it uses.

So, you basically will need to call [Cairo's C `cairo_xlib_surface_create`](https://www.cairographics.org/manual/cairo-XLib-Surfaces.html#cairo-xlib-surface-create) using Python ctypes, and find a way to create a Python cairo.XlibSurface instance using ctypes, from the pointer returned by the function above. That is the "missing link" that you probably have to findout in the pygtk legacy codebase, in C, and replicate with ctypes in the Python code.

As for the parameters needed for the  `cairo_xlib_surface_create` call on the first place, you likely can fetch them by using [Python XLib](https://pypi.org/project/python-xlib/)  -the snippet bellow gives you a Window GID and Python wrappers for the X Display and the Window:

```py
from Xlib import X, display
pd = display.Display()
win = pd.screen().root.create_window(0, 0, 640, 480, 0, pd.screen().root_depth, X.InputOutput, X.CopyFromParent)
win.map()
pd.sync()

xid = xx.__resource__()
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but not solve my problem.
I solved it using Gtk Window with `Gdk.WindowTypeHint.DESKTOP`.